# Insert blank rows in MySQL SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), MONTH(date), YEAR(date)
FROM activity
GROUP BY YEAR(date) DESC, MONTH(date) DESC
ORDER BY YEAR(date) DESC, MONTH(date) DESC
```

Which orders and groups records by month/date. Is there any way I can insert a blank row if a certain month doesn't have a record?

So, instead of this return:

```
c | M% |  Y%

4 | 01 | 2014     # 4 records for Jan 2014
3 | 11 | 2013     # 3 records for Nov 2013
7 | 10 | 2013     # 7 records for Oct 2013
```

I want to insert months for which no records could be found (Jan 2013 with count = 0), so I can have a neat visualisation of monthly activities.

```
c | M% |  Y%

4 | 01 | 2014
0 | 12 | 2013    # <<<< no records for Dec 2013, but I still want it in array
3 | 11 | 2013
7 | 10 | 2013
```

Comment: No, not directly. SQL cannot produce rows out of thin air, especially mysql. You'd have to have a temporary table that contains your full ranges of dates that you could join against. any rows which don't exist in your table but do in the temp table would have nulls in the appropriate fields.

Comment: So, it's better to do it in PHP then?

Comment: Yes - generally better. Incidentally, GROUP BY DESC doesn't mean anything!

Comment: Ah yes you're right, I copy-pasted GROUP statement from ORDER statement, which I wrote first.

Comment: Cool, I'll run it through a PHP loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to others, you can make up things in a MySQL query utilizing SQL variables.  My inner query creates a baseline date of one month ahead of whatever Now() is.  This is joined to the activity table just to get rows to work with.  The column is created by just setting the SQL variable equal to one month less than the month result of the previous.  In this example, I am doing a limit of 6 so it only goes back 6 months worth of data, but you can change that to however many you care about... as long as there are that many records in the "Activity" table (could be any table as long as it has as many records as you want to create these place-holder records).  This creates a result set of a 
what I have as "DynamicCalendar".  I then use this as the basis to do a left-join to the activity joined by month/year

```
SELECT
      MONTH( DynamicCalendar.GrpDate ) as Mth,
      YEAR(  DynamicCalendar.GrpDate ) as Yr,
      COUNT(activity.id) as Entries
   from 
      ( select
              @BaseDate := date(date_sub(@BaseDate, interval 1 month)) as GrpDate
           from 
              ( select @BaseDate := date_add(Now(), interval 1 month)) sqlvars,
              Activity,
           limit
             6 ) DynamicCalendar
      LEFT JOIN Activity
         ON MONTH( DynamicCalendar.GrpDate ) = MONTH( Activity.Date )
         AND YEAR( DynamicCalendar.GrpDate ) = YEAR( Activity.Date )
   group by
      MONTH( DynamicCalendar.GrpDate ) as Mth,
      YEAR(  DynamicCalendar.GrpDate ) as Yr
   order by
      YEAR(  DynamicCalendar.GrpDate ) DESC,
      MONTH( DynamicCalendar.GrpDate )
```